# sql server linked oracle how to execute query with dataset

Tags: sql-server, oracle, openquery

In sql server I have a table with id. I pass id through openquery in a loop.

```
while @coun < 1000
begin 
   select @id=id from #temp where num = @coun
   @sql = 'select * from tableoracle where id=' + @id
   execute('insert into #temp2 select * from openquery(ORAC, ' + @sql+')')
   set @coun = @coun + 1
End
```

Can I send the id immediately as a set and not one by one?

if you access the entire table at once in oracle without id, the request hangs, 
a lot of data

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

```
 declare @a varchar(max) = (select '(' + stuff (
(SELECT ',''' +id + ''''
  FROM #temp
  for xml path('')), 
  1, 1, '') + ')')
  @sql = 'select * from tableoracle where id in ' + @a
  execute('insert into #temp2 select * from openquery(ORAC, ' + @sql+')')
```

Comment: Any solution: use xmltable function in oracle and for xml in sql server